# Configuring PHP for MongoDB on Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: mac, php, mongodb, php.ini

I'm having some difficulty configuring PHP to integrate with MongoDB on my Mac.

I can confirm that PHP is running correctly, and the php.ini file I am tinkering with is the correct one (I can see phpinfo() results change accordingly).

I also have MongoDB running properly, from the command line and via a Node.js application.

I have installed PEAR, and have attempted to install the Mongo library via:

```
$ sudo pecl install mongodb
```

But this apparently fails with:

```
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/mongodb/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed
```

I guess this is why I can't find **mongo.so** or **mongodb.so** anywhere on my system, and why adding either of the following lines to my php.ini does absolutely nothing:

```
extension=mongodb.so
extension=mongo.so
```

This whole thing manifests itself in the browser as:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in /private/var/www/path/to/MyFile.php on line 8

And the code for MyFile.php is as follows:

```
<?php
// DEBUGGING
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

try {
    $m = new Mongo();
    $db = $m->selectDB("records");
}
catch (MongoConnectionException $e){
    echo '<p>Couldn\'t connect to mongodb, is the "mongo" process running?</p>';
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: Sorry @rahulb, I gave up in the end. I used AJAX calls to a Node.js API to get the job done, I think (it was a while ago).